# SQL Server, how to conditionally update multiple records?

Tags: sql-server

My table has these columns

```
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PersonID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[B] [bit] NULL
```

Given a list of `PersonID` values, I would like to update the table, setting the value of `B` for the most recent entry for each `PersonID` to 1.

The below script only updates a single record, but it seems something resembling it may work?

```
  UPDATE table
  SET B = 1
  WHERE PersonID in (<idlist>)
    AND ID IN (Select MAX(ID) FROM table WHERE PersonID in <idlist>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial script is very close. Just use correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE t
SET B = 1
FROM #tab t
WHERE t.PersonID in (<idlist>)
  AND ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #tab t2 WHERE t.PersonID = t2.PersonID);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412949)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong this is what you are trying to achieve

```
;with cte as
(
select row_number()over(partition by PersonID order by ID desc) as rn,*
from yourtable
Where PersonID in (<idlist>)
)
update cte set B=1
where Rn=1
```

Or use correlated sub-query

```
UPDATE A 
  SET A.B = 1
from table A 
  WHERE PersonID in (<idlist>)
  AND ID = (Select Top 1 ID FROM table B WHERE A.PersonID = B.PersonID 
            order by id desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN (Select MAX(ID) FROM ...)` limits to a unique MAX(ID).

Group by PersonID in order to get the MAX(ID) for each Person.

```
UPDATE table
  SET B = 1
  WHERE
    ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID)
           FROM table
           WHERE PersonID in (<idlist>)
           GROUP BY PersonID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is unique, your subquery just needs a correlation clause:

```
 UPDATE table t
   SET B = 1
   WHERE t.PersonID in (<idlist>) AND
         ID IN (Select MAX(ID) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.PersonID = t.PersonId);
```

Alternatively, you could use `group by`, but that would probably be more expensive:

```
 UPDATE table t
   SET B = 1
   WHERE t.PersonID in (<idlist>) AND
         ID IN (Select MAX(ID)
                FROM table t2
                WHERE t2.PersonID in (<idlist>)
                GROUP BY t2.PersonId
               );
```

The use of `row_number()` with an updatable CTE is another reasonable approach.